# Cython: Index should be typed for more efficient access

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cythonize

I am trying to port my pure python implementation to Cython and the function signature is as follows:

So my cython function signature is as follows:

```
cpdef cnmi_gradient_2d(double[:, :] jhlog,
                       double[:, :] reflog, double[:, :] warlog,
                       int width, int height):
```

I intend these to be numpy arrays in the pure python code and pass it to on to this function. At some point in the code, I access these arrays as:

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
         jl = jhlog[x, y]
         rl = reflog[x, 0]
         wl = warlog[0, y]
```

When I cythonise the code, I get the following warning: `Index should be typed for more efficient access`.

I am not sure what I am supposed to do with this? I followed this guide here: http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html

but not sure what I should be doing to solve this warning.

Comment: Maybe declare your arrays as C-contiguous `double[:, ::1] jhlog... ` or declare your indexes as `int`: `cdef int x, y`

Comment: Ah yes, I completely missed that. Thanks. If you want, please write it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it related to that you can easily fix this and this error is so you can see that there is a performance error there which you can easily fix.

The way to fix this is to do `cdef int` and then the names of the variables in the `for` loop.
In your code you should add before the outer for loop this:

```
cdef int x, y
```

Note that if it's not helping then you should do this at the same location:

```
cdef int x
cdef int y
```